# Google Cloud Platform: connecting to Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm using Google Cloud Platform with Apache Beam 2.1.0. I want to connect it to Cloud Bigtable, i'm following the official documentation in Apache Beam but i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getThreadFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.performWarmup(BigtableSession.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.<clinit>(BigtableSession.java:100)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableServiceImpl.tableExists(BigtableServiceImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO$Read.validate(BigtableIO.java:336)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$ValidateVisitor.enterCompositeTransform(Pipeline.java:610)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:590)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:276)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:210)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a dependency issue. It would make it easier to debug this if you could post a list of your dependencies from:

`mvn dependency:tree` or `gradle dependencies`

I'm guessing one of your other dependencies is transitively pulling in an older version of grpc-core or grpc-all on your classpath ( < 1.0 ). Apache beam depends on 1.2.0. Please make sure that you are using grpc > 1.2.0 and don't have grpc-all on your classpath.

Comment: i resolved this problem, but now i'm getting this one.    java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/IncrementAdapter.adapt(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment;)Lcom/google/bigtable/v2/ReadModifyWriteRowRequest$Builder; @97: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation'

Comment: Please update your question to include a list of your dependencies. The errors you are describing are very difficult to debug without an understanding of your environment. Please include: how are you managing dependencies? Is it via maven, gradle, etc? If so, please list the output dependencies from the tool. Are you manually adding jars to your classpath? If so, please list them. Are you running your code directly or is there a container that's loading your code (tomcat, jboss, hadoop,etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem by exclusing grpc from apache beam and adding it manually in pom.xml.

Now I'm getting this problem.

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/IncrementAdapter.adapt(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment;)Lcom/google/bigtable/v2/ReadModifyWriteRowRequest$Builder; @97: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @97
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/IncrementAdapter', 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment', 'com/google/bigtable/v2/ReadModifyWriteRowRequest$Builder', 'java/util/Iterator', 'java/util/Map$Entry', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment', '[B' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2bb6 0002 b600 039a 000d bb00 0459 1205
    0x0000010: b700 06bf b800 074d 2c2b b600 08b8 0009
    0x0000020: b600 0a57 2bb6 000b b900 0c01 00b9 000d
    0x0000030: 0100 4e2d b900 0e01 0099 009c 2db9 000f
    0x0000040: 0100 c000 103a 0419 04b9 0011 0100 c000
    0x0000050: 12b8 0013 3a05 2b19 04b9 0011 0100 c000
    0x0000060: 12b8 0014 3a06 1906 b900 1501 003a 0719
    0x0000070: 07b9 000e 0100 9900 5c19 07b9 000f 0100
    0x0000080: c000 163a 082c b600 173a 0919 0919 08b9
    0x0000090: 0018 0100 1908 b900 1901 0019 08b9 001a
    0x00000a0: 0100 b800 1bb6 001c 5719 0919 05b6 001d
    0x00000b0: 5719 0919 08b9 001e 0100 1908 b900 1f01
    0x00000c0: 0019 08b9 0020 0100 b800 21b6 0022 57a7
    0x00000d0: ffa0 a7ff 612c b0                      
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@20)
    append_frame(@51,Object[#72],Object[#73])
    full_frame(@111,{Object[#74],Object[#75],Object[#72],Object[#73],Object[#76],Object[#77],Object[#78],Object[#73]},{})
    full_frame(@210,{Object[#74],Object[#75],Object[#72],Object[#73]},{})
    chop_frame(@213,1)

    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.Adapters.<clinit>(Adapters.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableScanConfiguration$Builder.build(CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.java:157)
    at com.orange.pipelines.simplification.Simplification.run(Simplification.java:219)
```

Answer (score 1):

i delete all jar in WEB-INF > lib and it's works